# Return data from promise in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

i have an issue with a promise where I am unable to return the data from that promise...

I have tried different solutions so far, but I can't get it to work; I am new to promises and I am trying to understand what I am doing wrong:

```
 try {
      const classList = options.hash.class;
      const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, path.join(PATH.documentation, options.hash.startPath, options.hash.icon + ".svg"));
      let data = fs.readFileSync(filePath, "utf-8");
      let transformedSVG;

 // Promise
      const transformable = () => {

        // another promise... apparently
        svgo.optimize(data, { path: filePath }).then(function(result) {
          transformedSVG = result.data;
          transformedSVG = transformedSVG.replace(
            /^<svg/u,
            '<svg class=" ' + classList + '" '
          );
          return transformedSVG;
        });
      };

      // wait for Promise to be finished
      async function getResult() {
        let result = transformable;
        return result;
      }
      // wait for transformable to receive data and get the result
      async function doTask() {
        return await getResult();
      }

      // store svg data returned from doTask
      transformedSVG = doTask();
      console.log(transformedSVG);
} catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
}
```

any help with this?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing several things wrong. I fixed issues and added comment:

```
  const transformable = () => {
    // another promise... apparently
    return svgo.optimize(data, { path: filePath }).then(function(result) { // <== add return
      transformedSVG = result.data;
      transformedSVG = transformedSVG.replace(
        /^<svg/u,
        '<svg class=" ' + classList + '" '
      );
      return transformedSVG;
    });
  };

  // wait for Promise to be finished
  async function getResult() {
    let result = await transformable(); // <== call the function with `await`
    return result;
  }
  // wait for transformable to receive data and get the result
  async function doTask() {
    return await getResult();
  }

  // store svg data returned from doTask
  transformedSVG = await doTask(); // <== add `await`
```

One more thing to note is your `doTask()` method is doing nothing, so just remove it and call `await getResult()` directly.

Comment: `getResult()` doesn't *do* anything either, you could omit it and just call `transformable()` directly :-)

Comment: Thank you I appreciate that alot, problem is, that I can't use the await there, as I get the error message that I can use await only within an async function. I do get the result within the promise and I can console.log completely fine, but I cant return it so I get the actual data within my template q.q